# find in table and show only that rows

Tags: jquery

i am using this function to show only rows that are matched to search criteria, but i am stuck with numbers. I want to show only rows that are `> 0` or `< some number` for example.

```
function searchGrid(object,str) {
    var strary = str.split(' ');
    $(".mainGrid").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
        var text = $.trim($(this).find('.'+object).text());

        for (var i = 0; i < strary.length; i++) {
            var regex = new RegExp("" + strary[i] + "", "gi");
            $(this).toggle(regex.test(text));
                if (regex.test(text)) break;
            }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) to filter your tabular data. You just need to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

It automatically provides a search bar!

[image]

Comment: if i dont find solution for mine already existing code, i will use DataTables. Thanks.